# JavaScript/JQuery publish subscribe not working between two pages but works within a page in below code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html pages and a JavaScript file.

**Implementation**

`First html` page publish the message and the `second html` page subscribe to the published message and performs the action based on the published message in the second page.

**Problem Statement**

The publish and subscribe works fine within the same html page but has problem when working between two html pages.

The problem is, the subscribed message is being displayed in the First HTML Page but not in the Second HTML Page.

**First HTML Page**

```
<script>
        function clickMe() {
            messageBus.publish('event', 4);
        }
</script>
```

**Second HTML Page**

```
<script>
            messageBus.subscribe('event', function(data) {
                $("#div1").text(data);
            });
</script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

**JS File**

```
var messageBus = {
events: {},
publish: function(eventType, data) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      var myFunc = localStorage.getItem(eventType);
      var e = eval('(' + myFunc + ')');

      if(e) {
          e(data);
      }
    }
},
subscribe: function(eventType, fn) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem(eventType, fn);
    }
},
unsubscribe: function(eventType) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.removeItem(eventType);
    }
}
}
```

Is there something missed in the implementation? Let me know if there is more stuffs required to make the question clear.

Comment: Why on earth would you use eval?

Comment: @AdrianBrand When I remove the `eval` and call `e(data)` it's throwing `e is not a function exception` because `e` is getting parsed to string.

Comment: That is what JSON.stringify and JSON.parse are for, turning objects into strings and then you store the stringified object in local storage and use parse to turn it back into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main problem**

As already pointed out by [Adrian Brand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679126/adrian-brand) in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58021624/303685), the code inside your `publish` method and `subscribe` method need to be swapped.

**Other unrelated but design related problems**

1. Another problem with your `messageBus` is that it if the *publisher* publishes more than one message before the *subscriber* has had a chance to read any of the messages, only the last one of the messages published gets persisted to your *message bus*; all previous messages are overwritten by the last one and so they never make it to the *subscribers*.
2. You're using `eval` to run just about anything that might be inside the `localStorage` item. This opens your application up to a security threat.

   What if I opened your application in **Developer Tools**, wrote a malicious function or script and put it in the local storage with the key `'events'`? Your code would execute my function. Now, imagine all that I could do with that ability.

   I could make AJAX requests to evil websites (I would make them `GET` requests to bypass CORS), read your cookies, search for and scrape all your form fields, stuff them into a form data object and send that to my server, and a whole lot more.

Comment: Can you please help me with the sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your publish and subscribe methods are the wrong way around, publish is getting the item and subscribe is writing it. And get rid of that eval!